# video not playing smooth in ios using MPMovieController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am playing video using MPMoviePlayer from a url but video does not playing smoothly.It play then pause automatically then i have manually press play button to play the movie  please tell me how can i do that? i am trying below code.

```
 NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:self.image_url]];
            [self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
              self.moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height-40);
            self.moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
            self.moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
            [self.moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
            [self.moviePlayerController play];
            [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];
```

Comment: if u have not used [self.moviePlayerController pause]; any where in your class . then please try with reversing the ordering the last 2 line of code as : [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];  [self.moviePlayerController play];

Answer (score -1):

```
Use this code it will work
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:VdoFilePath];
    theMoviPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [theMoviPlayer setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
    theMoviPlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification   object:theMoviPlayer];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification object:theMoviPlayer];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willExitFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:theMoviPlayer];
    UIWindow *backgroundWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [theMoviPlayer.view setFrame:backgroundWindow.frame];
    theMoviPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    [backgroundWindow addSubview:theMoviPlayer.view];
    Ismovieplayerstart = TRUE;
    [theMoviPlayer play];
```